# Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘ClientR’

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to import a module with some data types into an exercise file
as shown below:

```
--SimpleFunctions.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

module Chapter2.SimpleFunctions
    (
    ) where

data ClientR = GovOrgR { clientRName :: String }
            | CompanyR { clientRName :: String,
                        companyID :: Integer,
                        person :: PersonR,
                        duty :: String}
            | IndividualR {person :: PersonR, ads :: Bool }
            deriving(Show)

data PersonR = PersonR {  firstName :: String,
                        lastName :: String,
                        gender :: Gender }
                        deriving(Show)

--exercise.hs
import Chapter2.SimpleFunctions

filterGovOrgs :: [ClientR] -> [ClientR]
filterGovOrgs xs = xs
```

the project tree structure looks like:

```
.
├── ProjectApproachBook.cabal
├── Setup.hs
├── chapter2
│   ├── Section2
│   │   └── Example.hs
│   └── SimpleFunctions.hs
├── chapter3
│   └── exercise.hs
└── dist
```

when I load exercise.hs in ghci I'm getting the error :

> Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘ClientR’

```
Prelude > :l chapter3/exercise.hs 
[1 of 2] Compiling Chapter2.SimpleFunctions ( Chapter2/SimpleFunctions.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( chapter3/exercise.hs, interpreted )

chapter3/exercise.hs:53:19:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘ClientR’

chapter3/exercise.hs:53:32:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘ClientR’
Failed, modules loaded: Chapter2.SimpleFunctions.
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue was that `ClientR` was not exposed in the Chapter2.SimpleFunctions module:

```
module Chapter2.SimpleFunctions
    (ClientR
    ) where
```